# How to split terminal in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: command-line, unity, 16.04

I've seen in some video that it is possible to split terminal window into several areas (not tabs), but can't found those video and can't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 5):

The default `gnome-terminal` doesn't support splitting,it only allows using tabs. What you want is either Terminator , byobu,or screen.

In the first case, Terminator is a standalone terminal emulator.
[image]

Byobu and screen are terminal multiplexers , which are basically apps that run inside terminal emulator.

Any of these can be installed via `sudo apt-get install <app-name>`